# pytest mysql db fixture: cannot create database

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, pytest, fixtures

I'm trying to use `mysql` from pytest-dbfixtures. I have a test file with example from documentation:

```
def test_using_mysql(mysql):
    mysql.query("SELECT CURRENT_USER()")
```

and when I run it via `$ py.test test_example.py`, I get this error:

```
    E               subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '/usr/bin/mysql_install_db --user=Fluffy --datadir=/tmp/mysqldata_3307' returned non-zero exit status 127

/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py:711: CalledProcessError
    ------------------- Captured stderr setup ------
   [ERROR] /bin/sh: /usr/bin/mysql_install_db: No such file or directory
```

I am using python 3.5 and OS X 10.11.5. MySQL 5.7.12 is installed via `homebrew`, and works well.

`homebrew` doesn't create symlimks to `/usr/bin`, only to `/usr/local/bin`. If I create the link manually:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.12/bin/mysql_install_db /usr/bin/mysql_install_db
```

I get the following error from pytest:

```
E               subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '/usr/bin/mysql_install_db --user=Fluffy --datadir=/tmp/mysqldata_3307' returned non-zero exit status 1

/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py:711: CalledProcessError
------------------------- Captured stderr setup ----------------------
 [ERROR]   Can't locate the language directory.
```

Also, script `mysql_install_db` is deprecated: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-install-db.html

How do I use `mysql` fixture from pytest dbfixtures? Is there a way to use it on OS X with MySQL 5.7?

Comment: Could you show a small example of how you are referencing the `mysql` fixture?

Comment: Just to clarify, the same example works on vagrant machine with Ubuntu.

Comment: You're using the latest version of `pytest-dbfixtures`, right?

Comment: pytest-dbfixtures==0.13.1, as far as I see that's the latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some info about my set up:

- Mac OS X 10.11.5
- Python 3.4.4
- MySQL Community Edition 5.7.13

I wasn't exactly able to reproduce the issue you are running into, but I think some of the information below should be useful.

Packages required:

```
pytest==2.9.2
pytest-dbfixtures==0.13.1
mysqlclient==1.3.7
```

I couldn't install `mysqlclient` initially (got: `"OSError: mysql_config not found"`), because `mysql` was not in the path.
Added `/usr/local/mysql/bin` to the path in `.bash_profile`

Now you need to configure `pytest-dbfixtures` to use your `mysql` connection.
For me, the .conf file was located here (I am using virtualenv):

`~/.virtualenvs/py3.4-PySA/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pytest_dbfixtures/conf/dbfixtures.conf`

For you, the config file should be somewhere in your Python 3.5 installation directory (navigate there and do `find . -name dbfixtures.conf`).

There's a section in `pytest_dbfixtures/conf/dbfixtures.conf` to set your `mysql` user, password, and the paths to local MySQL binaries **(no need to use symlinks)**.
You should have gotten a password for the `root` user when you installed MySQL (that said, you'll need to reset it to something new).

You might want to consider creating a new user for MySQL and use its credentials instead (perhaps look at the configuration on the Ubuntu server you referred to in the comments).

If you insist on using the MySQL `root` user, this might help. I went to check into `mysql` via the terminal and apparently trying to do `SELECT CURRENT_USER()` on the `root` MySQL user requires the following:

```
mysql> SELECT CURRENT_USER();
ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.
```

Using `ALTER`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Then go back to `dbfixtures.conf` and update the password accordingly.

Unfortunately, I get stuck here:

```
def stop_server_and_remove_directory():
        shutdown_server = (
            mysql_admin_exec,
            '--socket=%s' % unixsocket,
            '--user=%s' % config.mysql.user,
            'shutdown'
        )
>       subprocess.check_output(' '.join(shutdown_server), shell=True)

~/.virtualenvs/py3.4-PySA/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pytest_dbfixtures/factories/mysql.py:143: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

...
>               raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args, output=output)
E               subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin --socket=/tmp/mysql.3307.sock --user=root shutdown' returned non-zero exit status 1

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py:620: CalledProcessError
```

Executing the same `mysqladmin` command via the terminal results in an auth failure. Might just be me though.

Let me know how far you get.